# Image Recognition in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, image-recognition

I am creating an iPad app for golfers, I will get their score card image as below. I want to calculate sum of scores for each person by scanning this image.
Is there any way. Please give me a logic for this.

[image]

Comment: look in to "OCR" to get started.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have used opencv http://opencv.org in the past to do something similar but with sudoku puzzles.

It is a LOT of work and making it work with handwriting will add to the difficulty.

I found a really good resource for analysing sudoku grids. I'll try to find it again but it was 4 years ago.

Good luck though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Tesseract port for iOS which is about the best OCR you're likely to get on the platform without either:

A) Porting another OCR library

or

B) Shipping the images off to an online OCR service

To make this more complex, you don't just want to OCR but you want to OCR handwriting and put it into a grid. This is not something that can be done overnight but is in fact rather complex. Not impossible, but complex.

Would it not just be easier to let the players enter there scores straight onto the app and then airprint a score card?